# How to right-align a custom accessory view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using a button as a custom cell accessory view.  The button is working fine, but is not right-aligned in the cell.  There is padding to the right of the button, and if I tap to the right of the button, the cell is tapped instead of the accessory.   I thought the accessory view was right-aligned in the cell by default, and that's how it appears in the storyboard.  I would like to right-align the accessory view in the cell.

```
let alertButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 60))
alertButton.setImage("BellOutline", for: .normal)    
cell.accessoryView = alertButton as UIView
```